# How to detect user input in c#

Tags: c#

I've only had limited coding experience and i need help with my code. I want it when a user types "Y" or "N" the program is able to react accordingly to your decision and display a text response.
It would really help if it was explained clearly and dumbed down.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of App.? are you working on a console app?

Comment: Console.Readline() ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MSDN Console.ReadLine examples here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) might be useful.

Console.ReadLine usage looks like this:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.Clear();

      DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;

      Console.WriteLine("\nToday is {0:d} at {0:T}.", dat);
      Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue... ");
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the PO seem to want y/n key Hit I would suggest `Console.ReadKey()` rather than `Console.ReadLine()` as the later needs an extra entering.
`KeyChar` Property of the `ConsoleKeyInfo` gives the character user entered.

```
var x = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    if(x=='y'||x=='Y')
    {
    //do something
    }
    else if(x=='n'||x=='N')
    {
    //do something else
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: How about now.? Do you want to vote me up.??

Answer (score 1):

If you use a console you can use the [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
if (line == "Y")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Y was pressed");
}
else if (line == "N")
{
   Console.WriteLine("N was pressed");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine(line + " was pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //read from console
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        //treat read value
        switch(userInput)
        {
            case "Y":
                Console.WriteLine("Y was entered!");
                break;
            case "N":
                Console.WriteLine("N was entered!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```